# Is Adding package.json and installing modules considered as two different layers while building docker image?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

```
FROM node:boron

WORKDIR /app

ADD package.json /app

RUN npm install

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node","app"]
```

So my question is do the two lines `ADD package.json`, `RUN npm install`. Will be made two separate layers or one single layer while building the docker image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course. There will be two layers..see the [image](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTxaE-VFu4dBhBRD0dCelCraACQdtMMd8WykwNE-GROkk0jc_heaPbliAsf)